# Xcode remember the area the user selects

Tags: xcode, cookies

I am building an app where the user has to select the area they live in. Depending on where they live, it takes them to separate pages. Is there a away I can save which page the user selects and display that page every time they open up the app?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into cookies.

Simplest way to make them client side is with javascript:

```
document.cookie = "area=USER_AREA";
```

Then you can even use javascript client side again to redirect:

```
var cookie = document.cookie;
var area = cookie.slice(cookie.indexOf('area')+5);
document.location = "/" + area;
```